# How to get information regarding the most recent fetch?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and am having trouble understanding how fetch works.   If I understand correctly it makes your local repo match the remote repo.

I can't find any evidence of the fetch in `$ git log`. I see the most recent commit I made at the top of the git log but not the fetch, why is that?  Shouldn't I see information regarding the fetch in git log?

How can I get information about the most recent fetch and how can I diff local repo prior to the fetch against the fetch?

Comment: You may be confusing ``fetch`` with ``pull``. A fetch just updates your references to the remote repositories, a pull merges them. You can see those differences by running ``git diff origin/master`` (to see the diffs between your current HEAD and origin/master).

Comment: `git` doesn't log any information about fetches.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetch` you can evaluate code without actually merging it into your code base.  This is used to advantage for people that need to approve a pull request, for example.  It can also be used to advantage to avoid "merge commits" where you can fetch a commit and then rebase it or merge it into  your work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/485864) may be what you are looking for in detail.